# Problem running ethernaut hacks locally

Tags: hardhat, nodejs, openzeppelin

[link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XXz6zelbjvM) here is the link of the video which I was watching for running ethernaut locally.
At 5 min when running the command `yarn start:ethernaut` I came across a error:

```
Starting the development server...

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
at module.exports (/root/folder/ethernaut/ethernaut/node_modules/webpack/lib/util/createHash.js:135:53)
at NormalModule._initBuildHash (/root/folder/ethernaut/ethernaut/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:417:16)
at handleParseError (/root/folder/ethernaut/ethernaut/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:471:10)
at /root/folder/ethernaut/ethernaut/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:503:5
at /root/folder/ethernaut/ethernaut/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:358:12
at /root/folder/ethernaut/ethernaut/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:373:3
at iterateNormalLoaders (/root/folder/ethernaut/ethernaut/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:214:10)
at iterateNormalLoaders (/root/folder/ethernaut/ethernaut/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:221:10)
/root/folder/ethernaut/ethernaut/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/start.js:19
throw err;
^

Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:71:19)
at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
at module.exports (/root/folder/ethernaut/ethernaut/node_modules/webpack/lib/util/createHash.js:135:53)
at NormalModule._initBuildHash (/root/folder/ethernaut/ethernaut/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:417:16)
at /root/folder/ethernaut/ethernaut/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:452:10
at /root/folder/ethernaut/ethernaut/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:323:13
at /root/folder/ethernaut/ethernaut/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:367:11
at /root/folder/ethernaut/ethernaut/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:233:18
at context.callback (/root/folder/ethernaut/ethernaut/node_modules/loader-runner/lib/LoaderRunner.js:111:13)
at /root/folder/ethernaut/ethernaut/node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js:59:103 {
opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
library: 'digital envelope routines',
reason: 'unsupported',
code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}

Node.js v18.12.1
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

I am unable to resolve this error can someone please help.

Comment: Searching the error message suggest is a problem with the node version https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69692842/error-message-error0308010cdigital-envelope-routinesunsupported. Try downgrading to v16.